# Fetch parent record by applying Join on nested classes in DocumentDb

Tags: join, azure-cosmosdb

```
 public class Restraunt
 {
 public string RestId {get; set;}
 public ICollection <RestrauntType> RType {get; set;}
 }

 public class RestrauntType
 {
 public string Opinion {get; set;}
 }
```

If i have Opinion value as a string how can i fetch the RestId corresponding to Opinion value.
I have done it using .ToList() and it works but for large number of records i need more efficient technique like Joins, Can you please tell me how to proceed with Joins?

------------UPDATED----------------------------------
Changed my approach a bit and used joins and got a desired solution. Here is it

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Restraunt Join RType in Restraunt.RType Where        RType.Opinion = 'It works !' ";
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(documentCollection.SelfLink, sql).ToList();
```

It saved the effort of loading all queries to list and then fetching the desired field, just hit the query and get the field directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentDB follows the NoSQL trend and does not support cross-document joins. If the solution you have now is not performing up to your needs, you may be able to hand implement the join either client-side, or with a stored procedure (sproc) running inside DocumentDB. In my own work, if I can implement the join with two round trips, I favor client side because it utilizes secondary storage and has better throughput on a loaded system. Latency is 1.8x the equivalent done in a sproc, but throughput is better. If it takes more than 2 round trips, the latency is too high and I favor using a sproc. YMMV for your situation so you may need to run some experiments yourself. The nice thing about DocumentDB is that it provides a lot of opportunity to optimize to your situation rather than assume joins will be performant. Note, the join functionality in traditional databases makes it easier and enables faster development, but it can be a performance problem and those database don't provide as much flexibility to allow you to code your way out of performance problem as does DocumentDB.

**Update from comments.** Hand coding of joins is a big topic. Frequently in NoSQL, you trade off the performance of a hand join with denormalization that eliminates the join or makes it faster. The simplest algorithm for a join involves two round trips. In your case, it looks like RestaurantType is what I call a lookup type which is characteristically a small number. In that case, it's usually best to first fetch the entire lookup table (and cache it for some period if you want to be optimal). Then do your Restaurant query and hand stitch the lookup values into the table that is returned from that.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Larry ,do you know any source from where i can hand implement this sort of queries?

Comment: Hand coding of joins is a big topic. Frequently in NoSQL, you trade off the performance of a hand join with denormalization that eliminates the join or makes it faster. The simplest algorithm for a join involves two round trips. In your case, it looks like RestaurantType is what I call a lookup type which is characteristically a small number. In that case, it's usually best to first fetch the entire lookup table (and cache it for some period if you want to be optimal). Then do your Restaurant query and hand stitch the lookup values into the table that is returned from that. Make sense?

Comment: As said :) i hand stitched the query and it worked . Thanks for help.

Comment: Cool, can you please accept the answer? I updated it to include the hand coding of join information in this thread.